# Работа с датами и интервалами

Tags: oracle

Необходимо перевести все запросы с MySql субд на Oracle.

Mysql: `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, date_time, NOW()) < 24`

Oracle: `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (SYSTIMESTAMP - DATE_TIME)) < 24`

Но как понял второй запрос вычисляет только разницы в часах, без учета пройденных дней. Прошу подсказать как правильно работать с датами и вычислять интервалы времени

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE_TIME >= SYSDATE - interval '24' HOUR
```

По идее можно даже просто

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE_TIME >= SYSDATE - 1
```

Если нужно именно последние 24 часа.

Comment: Первый запрос мне подходит спасибо. А если к примеру при группировке я хочу по каждой записи посмотреть разницу в часах или минутах к примеру. По аналогу с TIMESTAMPDIFF что можно применить?

Comment: @quaresma89 Наверняка есть решения изящней, но моё простое решение:
 SYSDATE - DATE_TIME даёт нам дробное число, где 1 - это ровно 24 часа. Исходя из этого разница в часах это (SYSDATE - DATE_TIME)*24, а разница в  минутах (SYSDATE - DATE_TIME)*24*60. Можно убрать дробную часть функцией ROUND()

Comment: Ну или  CEIL() или FLOOR(), смотря как надо округлить.